# Why does $compile not evaluate the scope in directive created by ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive creating instances of another directive using `ngRepeat`:

```
app.directive('prMain', function(){
  return {
    accept:'AE',
    template:'<div pr-item="" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}<div>'
  };
});
```

The sub directive is like this:

```
app.directive('prItem', function($compile){
  return {
    accept:'AE',
    template:'<p>{{item.name}}</p>',
    compile: function(elem) {
      elem.removeAttr('pr-item');
      return function(scope) {
        console.log(scope.item.color);
        var newEle = $compile('<div ng-style="{\'color\':\'red\'}">DIRECTIVE item.name</div>')(scope);
        elem.append(newEle);
      };
    },
  };
});
```

I would have expected two `div`s for each element in the array, the last one colored.

Instead, I get a confusing succession of text in the browser:

```
one

two
DIRECTIVE item.name

three
DIRECTIVE item.name
DIRECTIVE item.name

four
DIRECTIVE item.name
DIRECTIVE item.name
DIRECTIVE item.name
```

Please refer to this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3B9Qlnh8USjoaPJuiDnn?p=preview).

The most important question is: why does `ng-style` not properly evaluate the scope expression? The second question is the reason for the output shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `compile` the right way. In particular, you are creating a closure of its `elem` parameter into the compilation method returned. Instead, each one of this function should work on its owm `elem`.

I'm not sure how to explain this, so here is some code and a fixed plunkr:

```
compile: function(elem_do_not_touch_elsewhere) {
  elem_do_not_touch_elsewhere.removeAttr('pr-item');

  return function(scope, elem_use_this_one) {
    var newEle = $compile('<div ng-style="{color:\'red\'}">DIRECTIVE item.name</div>')(scope);
    elem_use_this_one.append(newEle);
  };
},
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/aLyif5GxWySZs6RmZ6qm?p=preview